# Is there an elegant way in Ruby which acts like `require` in Scala?

Tags: ruby, scala, syntax

What I want to do is to make sure that arguments meet some conditions, if not, raise errors.

like this(let's say I want to make sure n > 0):

```
def some_method(n)
  raise "some error" unless n > 0
  ... # other stuffs
end
```

There is `require` method in Scala which tests an expression, throwing an IllegalArgumentException if false.

if there is something acting like that in ruby?

*I know ruby has `assert` series methods in unit test. But I don't think it is what I want.*

## EDITED

I just want to know if there are other ways to ensuring arguments meets some conditions, instead of `raise`.(The `require` in scala is so fit for that.)

Comment: How else would you want to write `n < 0`?

Comment: @sawa direct mimicking might be something like `require(n < 0, "no love for negatives")` although it is not a huge win in ruby (in scala difference is more significant).

Comment: @om-nom-nom Why the difference is more significant in Scala? `if (n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("some error")`. You still need `ArgumentError.new` in Ruby so they are even. Ruby doesn't have `@inline` though so implementing `require` is a performance hit.

Comment: @VictorMoroz [scala plain vs require -- 59 chars vs 28, ruby plain vs require -- 50 chars vs 28 chars](http://scalafiddle.net/console/24f0d2c90473b2bc949ad962e61d9bcb), I was talking about characters spent solely, good point about performance though.

Comment: @om-nom-nom You changed the 'if' to 'unless' in Ruby for four extra chars.

Comment: @MarkThomas chill, man :-) I had no goal to neither add characters to Ruby or cut characters from Scala, yeah, with `if` difference will be 50 vs 24.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with your initial try? It works fine if you indeed want to throw Exceptions. You can create a method to test the requirement if you want, but it does not really do much:

```
def req(cond, error)
  raise error if cond
end

def method(n)
  req(n < 0, ArgumentError.new('YOU BROKE IT'))
  # Method body
end

method(-1) # => method.rb:2:in 'req': YOU BROKE IT (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: I would move the `ArgumentError` into `req` if you're always going to be using it for arg checking.

Comment: @Max Yes, if that's the case then so would I. But perhaps he wants to use various custom Errors so I just kept `req` as generic as possible.  It was just an illustration anyway, he basically already had the right idea at the start :)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you want to specify the error class, and want to write the condition to be satisfied rather than condition not to happen, then there is no special thing you need.

```
def some_method(n)
  raise ArgumentError.new("some error") unless some_condition
  raise ArgumentError.new("another error") unless another_condition
  raise ArgumentError.new("yet another error") unless yet_another_condition
  ...
end
```